# Cannot render model fields in forloop with annotate() and values() (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am using `.values()` and `.annotate()`to sum up 2 models fields based on matching criteria.

I wrapped this in a `forloop` in my template to iterate.

Problem: I cannot call the model fields anymore. The forloop returns the venue_id instead of the name and the usual approach to call the logo does not work anymore.

(these were rendering fine before I used `.values()` and `.annotate()`. Makes me think I am missing something in the logic here. Any ideas?

**Models**

```
class Venue(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)
    logo = models.URLField('Logo', null=True, blank=True)

class Itemised_Loyatly_Card(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    add_points = models.IntegerField(name = 'add_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)
    use_points = models.IntegerField(name= 'use_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0)
```

**Views**

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
def user_loyalty_card(request):

    itemised_loyalty_cards = Itemised_Loyatly_Card.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).values('venue').annotate(add_points=Sum('add_points')).annotate(use_points=Sum('use_points')).annotate(total=F('add_points')-F('use_points'))
    
    return render(request,"main/account/user_loyalty_card.html", {'itemised_loyalty_cards':itemised_loyalty_cards})
```

**Templates**

```
{%for itemised_loyatly_card in itemised_loyalty_cards %}
<img"src="{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue.logo}}">

{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue}}
{{itemised_loyatly_card.total}}
{%endfor%}
```

**Renders**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns only the value ID because that is the only field you passed in as an argument to [.values('venue')](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values). Whereas if you want another attribute you have to use [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), like so:

```
.values('venue__name'. 'venue__logo')
```

Also, `.values()` returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries and not object instances, so if you pass that data into the template you can not access related data, meaning
`{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue.logo}}` will not work, but taking the first codeblock as an example `{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue__logo}}` works.

Another "mistake" is at these two annotations, annotations are a per object aggregation, these two lines are redundant, your model already has these fields.

```
.annotate(add_points=Sum('add_points'))
.annotate(use_points=Sum('use_points'))
```

That being said, if you want objects instead of values, that leaves you with:

views.py

```
itemised_loyalty_cards = (
    Itemised_Loyatly_Card.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
                                .annotate(total=F('add_points')-F('use_points'))
    )
```

template.html

```
{%for itemised_loyatly_card in itemised_loyalty_cards %}
<p>
    {{itemised_loyatly_card.venue.name}}
    {{itemised_loyatly_card.add_points}}-
    {{itemised_loyatly_card.use_points}}=
    {{itemised_loyatly_card.total}} 
</p>
<img src="{{itemised_loyatly_card.venue.logo}}" alt="" >
{%endfor%}
```